# wlan card not functioning in raspberry, yet shows up fine

Tags: wifi

I had my wifi running just fine, but i guess the problems started when i, against warning of damage to system, decided to run certain packet sniffer as a root. Now my AP appears fine, it asks for the wpa passkey( strange since itn emembers it), after that nothing, no error, no connection.

Tried various rebooting and resetting. Wlan0 seems to be up and in managed mode as it should.  Dmesg says:

> [Code] brxmfmac: brcmf_sdio_driverstrengthinit: No SDIO Drive strength
>   init done for chip 43430 rev 1 pmurev 24
>
> brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Dec 15 2015 version
>   7.45.41.23(r606571)
>
> Brcmfac: mrcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
>
> brcmfmac: brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev: wlan0 already exists
>   [/Code]

Other than that everything seems to be up and running. Any idea where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by reinstalling raspbian.